# Creating a Workflow Designer

Tags: java, framework, workflow

Our current application has a homegrown Workflow designer created with JSF as frontend/ Oracle as backend . It gives a user the ability to create his/her own workflows however this is tightly coupled with payments. We now want to provide the ability to have a similar yet generic Workflow designer to allow the user to create workflows for other entities within the application eg. invoices, contracts etc.

We would need some tool which has a rich API and the ability to drive this design using our own UI layer (and not using a Workflow designer). I would like to understand if Activiti or any other tool/product/framework can support such a design. Any recommendations or suggestions are most appreciated.